# Anchor: Error when calling idl function

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js

I keep getting this error after approving a transaction on my phantom wallet.:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account

Call Stack
Connection.sendEncodedTransaction
node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.browser.esm.js (7826:0)
async Connection.sendRawTransaction
node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.browser.esm.js (7783:0)
```

Here is the code:

```
const itemCreationAccount = await this.program.methods
  .createItem(itemInitialStock, itemPrice)
  .accounts({
    user: this.userPubKey,
    merchant: merchantPDA,
    item: itemPDA,
    mint: currencyMintAddress,
  })
  .transaction();

const transaction = new Transaction().add(itemCreationAccount);
let { blockhash } = await this.connection.getLatestBlockhash();
transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
//@ts-ignore
transaction.feePayer = this.userPubKey;

const signedTransaction = await this.anchorWallet.signTransaction(
  transaction
);
const txId = await this.connection.sendRawTransaction(
  signedTransaction.serialize()
);
await this.connection.confirmTransaction(txId);

const itemState = await this.program.account.item.fetch(itemPDA);
```

```
pub fn create_item(ctx: Context<CreateItem>, in_stock: u64, price: u64 ) -> Result<()> {
        let item = &mut ctx.accounts.item;

        item.merchant = ctx.accounts.merchant.key();
        item.price = price;
        item.items_in_stock = in_stock;
        item.mint = ctx.accounts.mint.key();
        item.thumbs_up = 0;
        item.thumbs_down = 0;
        Ok(())
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: First do a `try {} catch(err) { console.log(err) }` to get exactly where the error is from. If the logs confirm that it is a signer issue make sure you're generating the PDAs correctly

Comment: I get the same error:
Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account

Comment: Could you also share the code for the `createItem` instruction on the program

Comment: @C.OG we did a test with it and it worked fine but with keypairs with secretKeys. So it shouldn't be a problem with the program plus all the inputs for the idl are there.

Comment: @C.OG here is the code below
```
pub fn create_item(ctx: Context<CreateItem>, in_stock: u64, price: u64 ) -> Result<()> {
        let item = &mut ctx.accounts.item;

        item.merchant = ctx.accounts.merchant.key();
        item.price = price;
        item.items_in_stock = in_stock;
        item.mint = ctx.accounts.mint.key();
        item.thumbs_up = 0;
        item.thumbs_down = 0;
        Ok(())
    }
```

Comment: The relevant code is the `#[derive(Accounts)]` block for the offending instruction. Please add that code to your question instead of replying here with it, as it does not format properly in the comments section. But already I can see you're mutating `ctx.accounts.item` so my guess is that you forgot to mark it `mut` in the `Accounts` struct. Won't know for sure until you show the code.

Answer (score 1):

The error

`Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account`

is usually caused by one of two things

- you have not set the account to `mut`
- you haven't used the correct seeds for the account